# Firebase Web Api 9.22.2 New Modular Login Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

im currently trying to make a website that uses firebase as my Authentication and as my Data base. currently i am trying to make the login page for the website, i'm currently hosting the website and trying to run the it however every time i try and log in a user i am getting an error of Undefined : Undefined so i have no idea where to start. as well with this i am new to node.js so i'm essentially poking around in a language that i admittedly don't know much about. here is the JS code that i've wrote so far:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    //Private Verification Information
  };

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.2/firebase-auth.js";

const auth = getAuth(app); 

onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
    if(user != null) {
        console.log('logged in!')
    } else {
        console.log('no user');
    }
});

const userEmail = document.querySelector("#inputemail");
const userPassword = document.querySelector("#inputpassword");

signin.addEventListener('click',(e) => {

    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userEmail, userPassword)
    .then((userCredentials) => {
        const user = userCredentials.user;

        alert('signed in user!')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.errorCode;
        const errorMessage = error.errorMessage;

        alert(errorMessage + " " + errorCode + " : Error Signing In")
    })
})


console.log(userEmail + " " + userPassword + " " + authForm)
```

Comment: This has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Index.html:**

```html
...html above...

  <form class="signin">
<!-- Email input -->
<div class="form-outline mb-4">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"/>
<label class="form-label" for="email">Email address</label>
</div>

<!-- Password input -->
<div class="form-outline mb-4">
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"/>
<label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
</div>

<!-- 2 column grid layout for inline styling -->
<div class="row mb-4">
<div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">

</div>

</div>

<!-- Submit button -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
</form>

...HTML below...
```

**Main.js:**

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
      //Private Key
  };

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

import { 
    getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    signOut
 } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth(); 

onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
    if(user) {
        const uid = user.uid;
        console.log('logged in! : UID: ' + uid)
    } else {
        console.log('no user');
    }
});

const SignIn = document.querySelector('.signin');
SignIn.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const userEmail = SignIn.email.value
    const userPassword = SignIn.password.value

     signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userEmail, userPassword)
     .then((userCredentials) => {
         const user = userCredentials.user;

         alert('signed in user! User: ', user.user)
     })
     .catch((error) => {
         const errorCode = error.errorCode;
            const errorMessage = error.errorMessage;

            alert(errorMessage + " " + errorCode + " : Error Signing In")
        })
});
```

The main issue that was occurring was how I was referencing the inputs from the HTML data so you know where to look.
This is formatted where it will work with `firebase 9.22.2 modular` and is compilable with webpack for anyone having difficulty with webpack here you go. 
The HTML code does reference some CSS that I haven't included in this post so please take note of it if you are copying this for your projects.