# Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch with Firebase Auth - GoogleAuthProvider from firebase hosted website

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I've been watching videos on youtube about using firebase auth login with google popup pages and non of them ever go to or use Google Cloud and set up a OAuth 2.0 Client ID.
When running this code i get the pop up window from google however it throws a html 400 error and the error it returns states :

.

**You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.**

**If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details:**

**redirect_uri=https://www.{mywebsite}.com/__/auth/handler**

.

Ive tried going to google cloud and developers page and setting up an OAuth 2.0 Client ID and truthfully i don't understand where its going wrong

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
    //Private Firebase Config
  };

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

import { 
    getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    signOut
 } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth(); 

const GoogleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider(firebaseConfig);

GoogleProvider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
GoogleProvider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
```

*--SignInWithEmailCodeHere--*

[Firebase Web Api 9.22.2 New Modular Login Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76691957/firebase-web-api-9-22-2-new-modular-login-page)

```
const SignInWithGoogle = document.querySelector('.signinWithGoogle')
SignInWithGoogle.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()


signInWithPopup(auth, GoogleProvider)
.then((result) => {
  const user = result.user;

  alert('signed in user! User: ', user.user)
})
.catch((error) => {

  const errorCode = error.code;
  const errorMessage = error.message;

  alert(errorMessage + " " + errorCode + " : Error Signing In")

  const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);

  alert(credential.error + " : Error Signing In")
});
})
```

Comment: Just for extra details. I dont know how i would like the Google Cloud OAuth2.0 to Firebase. And the website is hosted through firebase, i saw some documentation saying things can be different if its hosted from firebases webhosting

Comment: make sure the spp is running https and your redirect URI is also https

Answer (score 5):

Solution found!

the problem was when i set up the firebase project i used a different domain and it defaulted to firebases default project domain "{projectname}.firebase.com" . i tried creating a new account not knowing firebase generates a service account for you automatically. this firebase cloud account can be found by going to

**project overview** ( top left) > **project settings** > **service accounts** > **manage service account permissions** (top right).

this will will take you to the google cloud page associated with your firebase web project from their you will click the 3 lines in the top left of the google cloud developer page and go to

**Api's & Services** > **credentials** (left hand vertical bar)

here you should see your google-generated OAuth2.0 settings. With these you can update them from

**"{projectname}.firebase.com"**
to
**"https://www.{yourdomain}.com"**

and for the redirect link from

**"{projectname}.firebase.com/__/auth/handler"**
to
**"https://www.{yourdomain}.com/__/auth/handler"**

Comment: I still sometimes get "If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console."